# Subtract 2 rows in Oracle

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I have on a table called file the next information:

```
No. DateTime
256 06/08/2015 01:47:43 p.m.
256 06/08/2015 09:56:24 p.m.
258 06/08/2015 01:47:43 p.m.
258 06/08/2015 09:56:24 p.m.
```

So, I need to make some operations to subtract:

```
256 06/08/2015 09:56:24 p.m. - 256  06/08/2015 01:47:43 p.m.
```

And to show the time difference.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code you can share with us to help you with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(DateTime) - MIN(DateTime),No FROM table
GROUP BY No
```

Comment: Thanks Shankar, it was so simple, sometimes i get stuck with simple things,cheers